# Heat Equation with Neumann Boundary Conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I was wondering if I was on the right track with this problem given that I have not had much guidance with them.

$u_{t}=u_{xx}+2u$

$u_{x}(0,t)=u_{x}(1,t)=0$

$u(x,0)=cos(\pi*x)+cos(3*\pi*x)$

So far I have:

$u(x,t)=X(x)w(t)$

$X(x)w'(t)=X''(x)w(t)+2X(x)w(t)$

$\frac{w'(t)}{w(t)}=\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)}+2=\lambda$

$w'(t)=\lambda w(t) \implies w(t)=Ae^{\lambda t}$

$X''(x)=(\lambda-2)X(x)$

$\lambda < 2$ and let $\sigma^2 = (\lambda - 2)$: $X(x)=Acos(\sigma x)+Bsin(\sigma x)$

Following through with this I get $\lambda = 2-\pi^2n^2$ so $X_{n}(x)=cos((2-\pi^2n^2)x)$

So would I just complete this by plugging it into $u_{n}(x,t)=a_{0} + \sum{a_{n}e^{\lambda_{n}t}X_{n}(x)}$ and solve using Fourier series? I feel like I did something wrong in my methodology of approaching this problem.

Comment: Do you mean $\sigma^2=\lambda-2$?

Comment: Yes I mean $\sigma^2=\lambda-2$ that was a typo I just fixed but $\lambda$ should be less than 2 I believe.

Comment: Right, $\lambda>2$ was a mistake on my part.

Comment: But $X(x)=\cos(\sigma x)$, not $\cos(\lambda x)$.

Comment: A hint to save you some difficulty: $u_t-2u=u_{xx}$,$e^{-2t} u_t -2e^{-2t}u=e^{-2t}u_{xx}$,$(e^{-2t}u)_t=(e^{-2t}u)_{xx}$. So you can solve the heat equation for $v=e^{-2t}u$ and then multiply by $e^{2t}$. This directly parallels the method of integrating factors for first order linear ODEs.

Comment: $X(x)=cos(\sigma x)$
$X'(1)=0 \implies -\sigma*sin(\sigma)=0 \implies \sigma = \pi*n$
$\lambda - 2 = \sigma^2 = (\pi*n)^2 \implies \lambda = 2-\pi^2n^2$

Comment: @lan so you would get an equation $-2\frac{w'}{w}=\frac{x''}{x}=\lambda$ then solve using conventional methods?

Comment: @user286417 You don't even need to change the equation for finding the separable solutions. Just solve for $v$ the way you normally solve the heat equation and then multiply by $e^{2t}$ at the end.

Comment: Alright thanks!